# multi-signatures signal management in user classes

Tags: c++, boost-signals

I'm very familiar with Qt and I know that we cannot have a similar synthax because we don't have the MOC part here. However I'm trying to have a signal creation management to simplify the declaration of a signal and the connection to it, inside my classes.

this is schematicly what I'm doing now

```
    class Foo
    {
       public:
          void connectMove(boost::signal<void(int)>::slot_type slot)
          void connectRotate(boost::signal<void(double)>::slot_type slot)

       private:
          boost::signal<void(int)> m_signalMove;
          boost::signal<void(double)> m_signalRotate;
    };
```

and this is basicaly what I would like to do (UPPERCASE = missing part)

```
    class SignalManager 
    {
       public:
          typedef boost::unrodered_map<std::string, GENERIC_SIGNAL *> MapSignal;
       public:
          template <typename Sig>
          bool connect(const std::string& strSignalName, boost::signal<Sig>::slot_type slot)
          {
             // simplyfied... :
             (*m_mapSignal.find(strSignalName))->connect(slot);
          }

          template <typename Sig>
          bool disconnect(const std::string& strSignalName, boost::signal<Sig>::slot_type slot)
          {
             // simplyfied... :
             (*m_mapSignal.find(strSignalName))->disconnect(slot);
          }

       protected:
          bool call(const std::string& strSignalName, SIGNAL_ARGS)
          {
             (*m_mapSignal.find(strSignalName))(SIGNAL_ARGS);
          }

          template <typename Sig>
          void delareSignal(const std::string& strSignalName)
          {
             m_mapSignals.insert(MapSignal::value_type(strSignalName, new boost::signal<Sig>()));
          }

          void destroySignal(const std::string& strSignalName)
          {
             // simplyfied... :
             auto it = m_mapSignal.find(strSignalName);
             delete *it;
             m_mapSignal.erase(it);
          }

       private:
          MapSignal m_mapSignals;
    };

    class Foo : public SignalManager
    {
       public:
          Foo(void)
          {
             this->declareSignal<void(int)>("Move");
             this->declareSignal<void(double)>("Rotate");
          }
    };


    class Other : public boost::signals::trackable
    {
       public:
          Other(Foo *p)
          {
             p->connect("Move", &Other::onMove);
             p->connect("Rotate", &Other::onRotate);
          }

          void onMove(int i)
          {
             /* ... */
          }

          void onRotate(double d)
          {
             /* ... */
          }
    };
```

I think I could resolve the "SIGNAL_ARGS" part with boost::functions_traits<>, but i don't know how to go around the abstract signal type.

1/ Is what I want even possible ?

2/ Is this a good approach ? (I know I will have some overhead due to the unordered_map.find, esspecily when I use this->call("signalname", ...), but I think it shouldn't be too significant)

3/ If this is not possible or not a good approach, do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by wrapping `boost::signals` and having a `boost::shared_ptr<IWrapperSignal>` instead of my `GENERIC_SIGNAL`.

The arguments probnlem was also resolved using `boost::function_traits<T>::arg_type`.

I don't know if it's the best way to do that, but it's working fine, and it is more simple for the user to declare signals in the classes that inherit this `SignalManager`.